# Has a top seed tennis player been disqualified from a grand slam tournament before?

Tags: trivia, tennis, atp, wta, grand-slam

Novak Djokovic, the top seed of US Open 2020 (and world #1 as of the start of the tournament) was [defaulted](https://www.espn.com/tennis/story/_/id/29825955/novak-djokovic-us-open-hitting-line-judge-ball) from his 4th round match against Carreno Busta after hitting a line judge with a ball.
This reminds me of when in 2009 also at the US open, Serena Williams was [given a point penalty](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1213164/Furious-Serena-Williams-dumped-U-S-Open-told-official-If-I-Id-ball-shove-throat.html) when down a match against Kim Clijsters point for verbally abusing a line judge. Serena was the second seed in that tournament, but the top remaining seed at the moment of the incident.

Has a top seed - male or female - in any grand slam ever been defaulted/disqualified from a match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was watching ESPN's coverage of the US open today (day after the incident). There was a few minute special coverage by [Tom Rinaldi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Rinaldi) on Djokovic's default after the Thiem vs Auger-Aliassime match. During that program with former #4 ranked player [James Blake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Blake_(tennis)), the host [Chris McKendry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_McKendry) mentioned that this was the first time ever the top seed had been defaulted in a grand slam tournament.

Comment: If I find the clip online I'll add a link for it

Answer (score 1):

At least in reasonably recent history, the answer is no.

The highest seed to have been defaulted (as opposed to retired voluntarily) was  John McEnroe (1990 Australian Open, 4th seed).  [This Sydney Morning Herald article](https://www.smh.com.au/sport/tennis/novak-djokovic-defaulted-tennis-players-disqualified-for-on-court-misconduct-over-the-years-20200907-p55t07.html) lists the disqualifications since 1990.

Serena Williams (2009 US Open, 2nd seed) also lost a match as a direct result of an official penalty, although she was not actually defaulted but rather lost a point penalty which happened to be the final point in the match.

Prior to 1990, the most recent Grand Slam disqualification [was in 1963](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/john-mcenroe-disqualified-from-the-australian-open), and I don't see anyone significant disqualified prior to that.

Comment: John McEnroe's disqualification was discussed by the commentators right after Djokovic's disqualification.

Comment: It is wrong that Serena Williams has been defaulted at the 2009 US Open. She received a point penalty that led to her losing the match. Taken from Wikipedia: "The violation ended up as a point penalty due to receiving a warning for racquet abuse earlier in the match, thus ending the match in controversial fashion"

Comment: @beta Hmm, it looks like you're probably right, although there's a lot more information out there using the word 'default' than not (including the piece I link to).  Thanks, internet.    I'll edit to make that clear, although I think it's appropriate to leave it in there in some fashion since she did lose the match on an official penalty (even though only a point penalty).

Comment: I am curious though if it would've been actually a default if she hadn't been in the doubles finals the next day; it seems like it was almost as bad if not as bad as what Djokovic did... there was some speculation about that in some articles.

Comment: Based on the facts, it was not a default. That's all I can say. Every person or article stating that she was defaulted is incorrect.